# Jira: Status tracking for multiple versions

Tags: jira, bug-tracking

We often have issues reported in JIRA for multiple versions of an application. However the fixes for these issues are not commited at the same time for every version the issue is reported for. This makes it hard to track in which version a fix was commited and developers sometimes forget to commit a fix for a version.

Is there a way to track the status of an issue for each version where it is reported separately, but in the same issue? In addition to a single status for an issue (which is only updated to a status when all versions have that status, i.e. an issue is set to "resolved" when it has been resolved in all fix versions), I would like to see a different status for each fix version.

After looking on the Atlassian-page I found an [old issue in their JIRA](http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-1493) which requests such functionality. Related to that there are forum discussions which suggest using a sub-task for each version. This would be a good solution if there was a plugin to automatically create the sub-tasks upon issue creation and fix version update. Is there such a plugin?

Comment: do you need separate workflow state for each version? can't you use Fix Version field and populate it with version the issue has been fixed in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a plugin. You can easily do this using standard JIRA functionality.

Just create a JIRA issue documenting the bug and then create sub-tasks for each version you want to fix the bug in. I usually use the parent issue to track fixing the issue in the latest (unreleased version).

In your JIRA configuration it might help to create a custom sub-task issue type called "Backport" to distinguish these issues from generic sub-tasks.

Comment: If you use the parent task for latest version don't you endup with the parent task being resolved before the subtasks?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but if I'm not mistaken JIRA is an Atlassian product and therefore you would do well to contact them with your question directly. I know the company and they are very good like that and would be more than willing to answer your questions.

(I feel that this qualifies as an answer of sorts even though it does not actually help)